# Original? Derivation of the sum of the first n natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Most derivations I have seen of this formula are rather complicated, and I was wondering if mine is completely original or if it has been done already. I found this derivation after proving the fact that every natural number is either even or odd in Spivak's calculus, and his way of deriving the formula is a bit less direct.

My neat little (not too rigorous) derivation only assumes that it is known that every natural number is either even or odd.

Assume firstly that n is even. We can note that the sum S= 1 + ... + n can be rearranged into n/2 pairs of natural numbers.  If each consecutive pair of outermost numbers are brought together (i.e (n+1), (n-1 +2), (n-2 +3), etc...), each pair reduces down to n+1 and thus S = (n+1)n/2.

Now assume that n is odd, and that S = 1+...+n. We know that n-1 is even, and thus S - n = (n)(n-1)/2, so that S = n + n(n-1)/2 = (n^2+2n-n)/2 = (n^2 + n)/2 = n(n+1)/2.

Comment: damn bro lets go hella einstein

Comment: but do you have a question haha

Comment: My question was whether my derivation was original

Comment: this is not original.

Comment: very good that you came up with this by yourself, but several others have too :)

Comment: Ah well, I am still proud of myself haha

Comment: And Tob, that proof is even simpler than mine and I like it way more

Comment: Another exercise: can you find the sum $S_n = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n$ for a given $x$ not equal to $1$?

Comment: still, great job man :D

Comment: The fact that you rediscovered the formula does show your hard work and insightful thoughts on the question. Be sure to apply them throughout your career!

Comment: Might like Versions of the Gauss Schoolroom Anecdote http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/gaussfiles/gauss-snippets.html

Comment: Tob, I actually derived that on my own as well. I reasoned as follows: if S(n) = 1 + ... + x^n, and x doesn't equal 1 (for which case it is a trivial computation) then S(n+1) can be written two ways: S(n+1) = S(n) + x^(n+1) = (n x S(n)) + 1, and solved for S(n)

Answer (score 2):

The standard derivation uses Gauss' trick:

\begin{align*}
S_{n} &= 1 + 2 + 3+ ... + (n-2) + (n-1) + n\\
&= n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 3+  2  + 1 \\ \\
\Longrightarrow 2S_{n} &= [1+n] + [2+(n-1)] + [3+(n-2)] + ... \\ \\
&= \underbrace{(n+1)+(n+1)+(n+1)+...}_{n} \\
S_{n} &=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \\
\end{align*}

Your own trick is quite similar and has been done before, which doesn't take away from the fact you found it yourself.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes thank you, forgot the factor of 2